# Command Line not Recognizing Latest Python Version

Tags: python, uninstallation

I lost track of which Python version I was previously using. I just finished installing Python 3.10.10, but when I open fresh CMD and type python -V, I get Python 3.8.5. I'm currently having issue installing tensorflow, and I want to make sure only 3.10.10 Python version exist on this machine.

The first thing I did was to try and locate Python 3.8.5 in Control Panel, but there isn't such a file. There's only two files with "Python" in the name exist in control panel: Python 3.10.10 (64-bit), and Python Launcher

Comment: `where python` should tell you where the `python.exe` is located at. Then you can delete the Python installation manually.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the installation path of Python, open the Start menu and search for the Edit the system environment variables entry, which opens up a System Properties window. In the Advanced tab, click on the button Environment Variables. There you’ll see User and System variables, which you’ll be able to edit.
In the section entitled User Variables, double-click on the entry and paste your Python path.

Comment: Searched python in start menu, only found the installation path for Python 3.10. How do I locate the python installation path of 3.8?

Comment: Reinstall Python 3.8 to a custom location. During the installation, click on modify path.

Comment: Where can I find the installer for Python 3.8? python.org only has maintenance packages, and I failed to find an actual installer for 3.8

Comment: https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/